# How to call two JSON data load parallelly in a proper way using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In my Case, I am trying to load two `tableview` data using two different `JSON`. Here, I need to know if I call both JSON load function at a time in main thread it is a good practice or anything need to do for a proper way of `parallel load`?

**My Code**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.loadJSONOne()
      self.loadJSONTwo()
}

func loadJSONOne() {
     // JSON Decoding with GET call here for URL one
}

func loadJSONTwo() {
     // JSON Decoding with GET call here for URL two
}
```

Comment: What's parallel load? Do you mean both methods need to run asynchronously without one waiting for another? Yes Swift is already asynchronous, they will be called parallely by default.

Comment: @Mumtaz Hussain Thank you. I just want to confirm it because. I thought it seems wrong one. Thanks :)